# Unable to connect to mysql (running in docker) from my java springboot application running in docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have a simple spring boot application which works perfectly while using local mysql data base. But when i hosted it in docker it is not starting up because it was not able to connect to mysql hosted in docker container.
my appliactaion.properties for the docker image is:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web = info
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/todo_example
spring.datasource.username=todouser
spring.datasource.password=todopassword
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-`strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`
```

and mysql docker ps command shows:

```
a43d27ade511        mysql:5             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   mysql
```

Spring boot application log says:

```
2020-04-26 10:39:36.651 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: Your application is also in docker container or just mysql ?

Comment: Are they two in the same docker network?

Comment: Application is also in docker

Comment: @setu yes same docker network

Comment: May be print the log of spring application startup failure? Try pinging from spring-boot container to mysql manually and see what result you get

Comment: @setu shared log..

Comment: show how u run mysql image && your app image

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib. docker run -p 8080:8080 my-todo-app --> my application and docker run -d --name mysql -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todo_example mysql:5 --> mysql